# O que é o inferno dos callbacks?

Tags: javascript, callback

Passando por algumas pesquisas recentes, cheguei a um termo desconhecido por mim: "The callback hell" ou "O inferno dos callbacks".

Fiquei curioso e decidi pesquisar um pouco, chegando ao seguinte trecho de código:

```
fs.readdir(source, function (err, files) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error finding files: ' + err)
  } else {
    files.forEach(function (filename, fileIndex) {
      console.log(filename)
      gm(source + filename).size(function (err, values) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error identifying file size: ' + err)
        } else {
          console.log(filename + ' : ' + values)
          aspect = (values.width / values.height)
          widths.forEach(function (width, widthIndex) {
            height = Math.round(width / aspect)
            console.log('resizing ' + filename + 'to ' + height + 'x' + height)
            this.resize(width, height).write(dest + 'w' + width + '_' + filename, function(err) {
              if (err) console.log('Error writing file: ' + err)
            })
          }.bind(this))
        }
      })
    })
  }
})
```

**Por que isso é ruim?**

**Como posso evitar?**

**Qual as alternativas para não se cair nesse inferno de callbacks?**

Comment: Não tenho interesse em responder, então só vou comentar que isso acontece porque as pessoas procuram os caminhos mais complicados. Curiosamente os mais experiente que poderiam lidar melhor com isso evitam abusar de um recurso que foi feito para uso parcimonioso.

Comment: Mas então não há vantagem em usar callbacks?

Comment: Desta forma eu acho que não, se trocar isso for `for` da linguagem é muito mais simples e não tem problema algum., provavelmente até o `readdir` não precisaria disto, mas se usar só ele não causa o problema relatado. Claro que tem vantagem em casos específicos, não o abuso. Quase sempre um `forEach()` é um erro.

Comment: "Quase sempre um forEach() é um erro." Você poderia explicar melhor essa afirmação?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## O que é o Inferno dos Callbacks

Usando o seu próprio código como exemplo. Podemos ver que o inferno dos callback é definido por essa piramide no final de `})`. Simplesmente horrível.

Segue o trecho:

```
            })
          }.bind(this))
        }
      })
    })
  }
})
```

## Como posso evitar?

O único jeito de evitar o inferno dos callbacks é mantendo uma boa prática em seus códigos. Sendo essas práticas

#### **1. Mantenha o Código Limpo e Fácil**

Esse é um exemplo de um código que claramente está ruim.

```
var form = document.querySelector('form')
form.onsubmit = function (submitEvent) {
  var name = document.querySelector('input').value
  request({
    uri: "http://example.com/upload",
    body: name,
    method: "POST"
  }, function (err, response, body) {
    var statusMessage = document.querySelector('.status')
    if (err) return statusMessage.value = err
    statusMessage.value = body
  })
}
```

Vamos dar nome as `functions`

```
var form = document.querySelector('form')
form.onsubmit = function formSubmit (submitEvent) {
  var name = document.querySelector('input').value
  request({
    uri: "http://example.com/upload",
    body: name,
    method: "POST"
  }, function postResponse (err, response, body) {
    var statusMessage = document.querySelector('.status')
    if (err) return statusMessage.value = err
    statusMessage.value = body
  })
}
```

Dar nome as funções tem benefícios imediatos como:

- Faz o código facil de ler graças a descrição da função em seus nomes,
  acima temos postResponse e formSubmit, que são auto-explicativos.
- Quando exceções ocorrerem você irá obter traços mais informativos de
  onde está o problema diretamente nas funções, invés de estranhos
  "anonymous".
- Permite referenciar suas funções.

Por fim você pode mover as funções para o topo do programa e dificilmente irá ter problemas com o inferno dos callbacks.

```
document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = formSubmit

function formSubmit (submitEvent) {
  var name = document.querySelector('input').value
  request({
    uri: "http://example.com/upload",
    body: name,
    method: "POST"
  }, postResponse)
}

function postResponse (err, response, body) {
  var statusMessage = document.querySelector('.status')
  if (err) return statusMessage.value = err
  statusMessage.value = body
}
```

#### **2. Modularize**

Qualquer um que fizer uma correta modularização do código, dificilmente irá ter problema com o inferno dos `callbacks`.

Criando um arquivo chamado `formuploader.js` que contém nossas duas `functions` anteriores, nós podemos usar o `module.exports` para modularizar tudo:

```
module.exports.submit = formSubmit

function formSubmit (submitEvent) {
  var name = document.querySelector('input').value
  request({
    uri: "http://example.com/upload",
    body: name,
    method: "POST"
  }, postResponse)
}

function postResponse (err, response, body) {
  var statusMessage = document.querySelector('.status')
  if (err) return statusMessage.value = err
  statusMessage.value = body
}
```

Em Node.js temos o famoso require, porém também podemos usar esse require no nosso navegador com [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify). Assim temos acesso ao require, podendo assim chamar o módulo que criamos no arquivo `formuploader.js` e depois utilizando o modulo criado.

```
var formUploader = require('formuploader')
document.querySelector('form').onsubmit = formUploader.submit
```

E agora temos duas vantagens vitais. Sendo duas delas:

- Fácil de ler por novos desenvolvedores
- formuploader pode ser usado em outros lugares.

#### **3. Evite erros**

Com toda certeza erros podem acontecer, você precisa cuidar para que eles não passem pelo código sem você saber onde eles estão. Muitos callbacks são construídos com um argumento que nos ajuda a tratar desses erros.

Por exemplo:

```
var fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('/Does/not/exist', handleFile)

function handleFile (error, file) {
     if (error) return console.error('Uhoh, there was an error', error)
     // otherwise, continue on and use `file` in your code
}
```

perceba o argumento error sendo tratado em `return console.error('Uhoh, there was an error', error)` extremamente importante caso ocorra algum problema.

[Mais Sobre Callback Hells ou Inferno dos Callbacks](http://callbackhell.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Em vez de callbacks, você pode usar promessas ("**promise**"). Hoje em dia já podes usar promises com quase tudo. Elas foram criadas para aliviar o callback hell.

Por exemplo, você faz um pedido HTTP para pegar as informações básicas de uma pessoa. Depois disso, pega o id da pessoa e procura pelo endereço usando outro pedido. Depois que a resposta vier, você faz mais outro pedido, usando o endereço da pessoa para pegar o número de compras ou algo assim. Segue o código:

```
encontrarPessoa()
  .then(response => {
    // Faz alguma coisa depois que pegar os dados básicos da pessoa.
    return pegarEndereco(response.id); // argumento: id da pessoa
  })
  .then(response => {
    // Faz alguma com o endereço obtido.
    return procurarCompras(response.completo); // endereço completo
  })
  .then(response => {
    // Faz alguma coisa com as compras
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Tem que lidar com os errors aqui
    console.log('Deu problema!', error);
  });
```

Um detalhe é que as funções que fazem o pedido HTTP acima tem que retornar uma [**Promise**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), senão o negócio não funciona. A resposta de encontrarPessoa() retorna uma **promessa**. Se a promessa for um sucesso (não teve problema), o bloco **then** vai ser chamado. E aí, quando você retorna uma outra promessa de dentro de um **then**, o resultado, se der tudo certo, vai pro **próximo** bloco de **then**. E assim por diante. Se der algum problema em qualquer uma das respostas, o bloco **catch** é chamado e você pode lidar com o **erro** lá.

Comment: Interessante. É suportado pela maioria dos browsers atuais?

Comment: @ArturTrapp de acordo com a documentação, Promise é suportada desde o ES6 ("ECMAScript 2015"). Normalmente de um jeito ou de outro, dá para usar por causa de polyfill e implementações third-party. No caso do lado do servidor, com Node.js, já é suportada faz tempo. Veja esse chart: http://node.green/