# Por que essa função não retorna valores

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

Estou fazendo uma função mais genérica para realizar chamadas AJAX, em que eu coloco a URL que deve ser buscada e os dados que ela deve enviar, e espero como retorno os dados carregados.

No entanto, não estou conseguindo, já que dentro da função se eu der um `console.log` ele mostra os dados, mas quando a função retorna os dados quando vou utilizar ela retorna `undefined`. O que poderia ser?

```
let amigos = retornaInformacoes('/amigos', '');
console.log(amigos) //undefined
function retornaInformacoes(url, dados = ''){
  $.ajax({
     type: 'post',
     url: url,
     data: dados,
     dataType: 'json',
     success: informacoes =>{
        console.log(informacoes) // aqui mostra os dados
         return informacoes;
     },
     error: erro =>{
         return erro
     }
 })
}
```

Comment: Isso realmente vai acontecer por conta do comportamento assíncrono do JS, o que você pretende fazer com esse retorno?

Comment: vou mostrar os dados para o usuário, estou tentando fazer isso, pois criei vários $.ajax, achei melhor criar uma função que só recebesse o a url e o dados e dentro de cada função tratar de maneira diferente

Comment: No callback do success, você pode colocar a sua função que manipula o DOM e exibe os dados para o usuário.

Comment: Eu já tinha feito isso, porém como lhe falei, estou repetindo muitos $.ajax e queria evitar isso, criando uma função que retornasse os dados e tratar dentro da função, isso dá pra fazer ? utilizando o $.ajax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que ocorre é que você está dentro de uma função de um [callback](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27177/o-que-%C3%A9-callback), então, o `return` que você está usando não irá retornar um valor da função `retornaInformacoes`, mas sim do callback:

```js
function retornaInformacoes() {
  $.ajax({
    // ...
    success: (data) => {
      // O return abaixo está retornando um valor para a função
      // que você passou como callback. (A arrow function).
      return data;
    }
  });
}
```

E os callbacks estão sendo usados já que o `$.ajax` é uma operação assíncrona. Logo, não há como não usá-los neste caso.

Então o que você precisa fazer é fazer com que a sua função `retornaInformacoes` aceite um `callback` ou retorne uma [`Promise`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises?hl=pt-br). Abaixo irei demonstrar os dois casos...

### Passando um callback

Pessoalmente, eu não usaria essa abordagem, já que hoje em dia, com as novas *features* do JavaScript (como as promessas), os callbacks não são a melhor opção.

Mas se você estiver executando seu código em ambientes que podem não suportar essas novas features, sugiro que você siga em frente com essa abordagem. No entanto, como você está utilizando *arrow functions* e outros recursos mais modernos do JavaScript em seu exemplo, esse não me parece o seu caso.

Enfim, se você quiser usar um callback pode fazer assim:

```js
function getData(url, callbackFn) {
  $.ajax({
    url,
    success: (data) => {
      // Note que estamos invocando a função de callback assim que a
      // chamada AJAX é finalizada com êxito.
      //
      // NOTA:
      // Como não houveram erros, estamos passando como primeiro
      // argumento o valor `null`, já que, por convenção, em um callback,
      // os erros vêm no primeiro parâmetro.
      callbackFn(null, data);
    },
    error: (error) => {
      // Note que agora, como houve erro, estamos passando como
      // primeiro argumento do callback o nosso objeto de erros.
      callbackFn(error, null);
    }
  });
}

// Para usar, só precisamos passar uma função como callback.
// No nosso caso, essa função deverá ser passada como segundo argumento.
//
// O seu primeiro parâmetro será um eventual erro;
// O segundo parâmetro serão os dados.
getData('https://api.github.com/users/lffg', (error, data) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error('ERR! Houve um erro!');
  } else {
    console.log(`${data.login} tem ${data.public_repos} repositórios no GitHub!`);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

### Utilizando promessas ([`Promise`](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/promises?hl=pt-br))

Esse, na minha opinião, é a melhor opção a se considerar nos dias de hoje quando se trabalha com operações assíncronas no JavaScript em casos como este.

Basta fazer assim:

```js
function getData(url) {
  // Note que a nossa função `getData` sempre retornará uma nova `Promise`.
  //
  // Como você pode ver na linha abaixo, as promessas recebem dois
  // parâmetros, um `resolve` e outro `reject`. Você deverá usá-los para indicar
  // a resolução ou rejeição da nossa nova promessa.
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax({
      url,
      success: (data) => {
        // Note abaixo que estamos chamando o `resolve` da nossa `Promise`:
        resolve(data);
      },
      error: (error) => {
        // Note abaixo que estamos chamando o `reject` da nossa `Promise`:
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  });
}

// Para usar, só precisamos chamar a função e depois "concatenar" uma chamada
// `.then` para fazer uso dos dados resolvido, e um `.catch` para tratar os
// eventuais erros.
getData('https://api.github.com/users/lffg')
  .then((data) => console.log(`${data.login} tem ${data.public_repos} repositórios no GitHub!`))
  .catch((error) => console.error('ERR! Houve um erro! ->', error));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Como você pode ter visto acima, as promessas tornam o nosso código muito mais legível, já que evitamos os callbacks. Isso se torna ainda mais evidente quando você precisa trabalhar com várias operações assíncronas seguidas. Essa abordagem das promessas ajudam a resolver um antigo problema do JavaScript chamado [*callback hell*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/188656/o-que-%C3%A9-o-inferno-dos-callbacks).

Ademais, há uma outra vantagem em se trabalhar com as promessas: a possibilidade de se trabalhar com [funções assíncronas](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas) ([`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)). Essa é, de fato, uma das melhores! Saiba mais [neste guia](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions?hl=pt-br).

Como leitura adicional, acho válido ler [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/379215/69296), que trata de um assunto semelhante.